# Add attachments at bmc remedy ticket creation time via api

Tags: remedy

I am able to create tickets via the bmc remedy webservice api, but I am having trouble with attachments.

I can get a single attachment added to the ticket at creation time, but I do not see a way to add multiple attachments at creation time.

I only see a namespace for Attachment1 in the wsdl file:

```
<xsd:element name="OpCreate" type="s0:CreateInputMap"/>
<xsd:complexType name="CreateInputMap">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Add_Time_spent__hrs" type="xsd:double"/>
    <xsd:element name="Add_Work_Done" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Application_Interface" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assigned_Group" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assigned_Group_ID" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assigned_Person" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assigned_To" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assignee_ID" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Assignee_Login" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Attachment_Status" type="s0:Attachment_StatusType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Attachment1_attachmentName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Attachment1_attachmentData" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    <xsd:element name="Attachment1_attachmentOrigSize" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="Category" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Details" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="HasAttachment" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Impact" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="InstanceId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Keyword" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Menu_Item_ID" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Notification_Type" type="s0:Notification_TypeType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Notify_Email" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Notify_Full_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Notify_Login" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="One_Line_Summary" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Parent_Saved" type="s0:Parent_SavedType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Priority" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Property_Tag" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Record_Source" type="s0:Record_SourceType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Request_Type" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Resolution" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Short_Description" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Site" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Status" type="s0:StatusType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Subject" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter_Department" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter_Email" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter_Full_Name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter_Location" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Submitter_Phone" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Topic" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Work_Done_History" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="ztmp_InstanceId" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When I do a call to OpCreate, all I can do is add Attachment1 data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple attachments are not supported via the GUI or the API. Other options would be:

- Package the attachments as a [zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)
- Package the attachments as a [multipart email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996514/inline-images-in-email-using-javamail)