# Unable to send html email using JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send html as email from `JavaMailSender`. The `html` has an `<img>` tag.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true);
mimeMessageHelper.setTo("preetham.kv@highpeaksw.com");
mimeMessageHelper.setText("<img src=cid:netLogo\" />",true);
ClassPathResource netLogoImg = new ClassPathResource("sample.png");
mimeMessageHelper.addInline("netLogo",netLogoImg);
mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

But when the email is sent, the image is going as an attachment rather than the image of the email content. How to send html's with image and link from `spring-boot`?

Comment: Please look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996514/inline-images-in-email-using-javamail

Comment: When you use cid while setting the images in email content it uses the attached images. Upload image in the server and use complete URL to image.

Comment: But in the gmail app, it is displaying properly

Comment: @mallikarjun after changing the code to `mimeMessageHelper.setText("<img src="+imageUrl+ "/>",true);` No image is coming!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to warp your Html content in a String and you use bellow code

```html
    
        MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) getNewMessageInstance();//sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
        try {
            if (emailContent == null || emailContent.length() == 0) {
                message.setContent(multipart);
            } else {
                message.setContent(emailContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception while setting message content ",e);
        }
```