# Don't want Images as an attachment but need it inline

Tags: java, email

I have this code to include images in email using Java.

```
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource imageSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageToByteArray(image, format), type);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(imageSource));
messageBodyPart.setContentID(imageContentID);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

But my images are shown as attachments as well as inline. What is wrong in it ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Inline images in email using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996514/inline-images-in-email-using-javamail).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. I had not set filename in the body part.

   messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
2. I was setting format and type as "jpg","image/jpg" respectively instead of "png","image/png"

   DataSource imageSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageToByteArray(image, format), type);