# Send mail containing inline image through SMTP in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, inline-images

How to add inline image to mail to sent it through SMTP in Java?

```java
helper.addInline("contentid", resource);
```

where `resource` is `ByteArrayResource`.

But I am getting `NullPointerEcxeption` before this line exactly.

`helper` is `MimeMessageHelper`.

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline images in email using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996514/inline-images-in-email-using-javamail)

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _but I am getting `NullPointerEcxeption` before this line exactly_ Pardon me but it's not clear. Is the line of code you posted throwing `NullPointerException` or is the line of code before that line throwing the exception?